# Android TextColor

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Does anyone know the way in which i am meant to code the change i want to make to the color of the ActionBar? I have tried using android:textColor , and android:color , as well as various other things. It seems like a quite a hassle for me. Although there is most probably a simple solution for this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Note: i am trying to make the font color white - from what i can tell, Android does this from the "actionbar.solid.pp" style.

```
<style name="Theme.Pp" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_pp</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Pp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Pp</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Pp</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Pp</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Pp</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_pp</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_pp</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Pp</item>

</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Pp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">#111</item>
    <item name="android:color">#FFF</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Pp</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Pp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_pp</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Pp</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.Pp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_pp</item>    
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.Pp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_pp</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Pp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.Pp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_pp</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_pp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_pp</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.Pp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_pp</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Pp" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_pp</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.Pp.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Pp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Pp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: show us what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

Changing the action bar's text color is shown on the developer guide [Styling the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomText)

Comment: I'll always upvote a reference to the proper documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this free tool to customize the style:
http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100